# How to struct a knowledge management system using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rolify

I am trying to create a kind of content management system to manage new ideas. In this system, there will be three roles, admin, user, and expert which I will define using Rolify and Devise gems.

The way this system works is that a user submits a new text (idea) first. This new text should go to the admin user. Then, the admin takes a look at that and if it was fine, it sends the idea to some of the expert users (admin specifies to which experts). Each expert user reads the idea and gives a rating to that idea. If that particular idea gets a minimum rating, it will be passed, otherwise it will be rejected and the user has to modify the idea.

WHat I have in mind is to define three roles, and a model for the idea. But what I am mostly confused about is how to pass the idea (text) between different users (from user to admin user, from admin user to expert user).

I would really appreciate it if you can help me.

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: Maybe you can add some fields to the Idea model. Something like these booleans: checked_by_admin approved_by_admin . If they are both true. The experts can see it in their Idea#show action. If only one expert has to see it, another field with name of expert will be required.

Comment: Don't pass the idea but set its state. Each role fetches the idea that can be handled by that role. You can add a new model, say `ReviewRequest` which `belongs_to :idea` and `belongs_to :expert`. This allows admin to assign the review request to multiple experts.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the idea of ReviewRequest, but would you please explain how admin would assign the review request? do you mean just assigning that to a expert(setting the expert user ID)?